# Why the code shows segmentation fault?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, network-programming

Since I know that segmentation fault occurs when we access a memory location which is not allocated by the OS , what causes here for the same?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
if(argc<3 || argc>4)
   {
     //diewithusermsg("Parameters","<Server_Address> <Echo_String> <Port_number>");
          }
const char* servip = argv[1];
char* echostring = argv[2];
in_port_t servport = (argc==4)?atoi(argv[3]):7;
int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sock<0)
 {
//diewithsysmsg("socket() failed");
}
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
 servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
int rtnval = inet_pton(AF_INET,servip,&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
return 0;
}
```

at servip parameter of inet_pton

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I know , its deviating at  inet_pton

Comment: Sure - so the next step is to use your debugger to inspect the parameters you are passing to the function.

Comment: the second parameter as mentioned

Comment: Are you passing any parameters to `main()`?  What's the value of `servip`?  You can add something like `fprintf( stderr, "servip: %s\n", servip );` right before calling `inet_pton()`.  (Use `fprintf(()` to `stderr` since `printf()` is buffered and might not emit its output if you still get a segmentation fault.)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle , I was missing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass parameters to the program, the program will crash. Pass parameters and it doesn't crash:

```
> valgrind ./a.out 127.0.0.1 foo 80
==22863== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22863== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22863== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22863== Command: ./a.out 127.0.0.1 foo 80
==22863== 
servip: 127.0.0.1
==22863== 
==22863== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22863==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22863==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==22863== 
==22863== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22863== 
==22863== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22863== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Code unchanged:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc<3 || argc>4)
    {
        //diewithusermsg("Parameters","<Server_Address> <Echo_String> <Port_number>");
    }
    const char* servip = argv[1];
    char* echostring = argv[2];
    in_port_t servport = (argc==4)?atoi(argv[3]):7;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock<0)
    {
//diewithsysmsg("socket() failed");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    fprintf( stderr, "servip: %s\n", servip );
    int rtnval = inet_pton(AF_INET,servip,&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    return 0;
}
```